# Rake custom arguments for all tasks?

Tags: ruby, rake, arguments

I want to pass in an argument to rake independent of the task I run.

For example:

```
rake my_arg=foo
rake my_arg=foo :install
rake my_arg=foo :upgrade
rake my_arg=foo :bar
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send arguments in like this:

```
rake some_task arg1=value arg2=value
```

Then pull the named parameters out of `ENV` inside your rake task:

```
arg1 = ENV['arg1']
arg2 = ENV['arg2']
```

You can also supply more traditional command line switches like this:

```
rake some_task -- --arg1=value --arg2=value
```

And then use [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/classes/OptionParser.html) (or some other option parser) to unpack `ARGV`. Don't forget the extra **`--`** if you want to use switches, that will tell `rake` to stop parsing the command line as switches.

Comment: Will this require running a specific task?  I'm trying to make this work without having to specify any task when running rake. e.g. rake -- --arg1=value

Comment: @Misha: The `--` option needs to be handled by each task. Everything after the `--` should be available in `ARGV` when running tasks through a Rakefile; you should have access to `ARGV` and `ENV` as long as you're in Ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

These arguments are put into `ENV[]` by rake, simulating environment variables. As such, you can just use actual environment variables instead. For instance:

```
export my_arg=foo
rake install upgrade bar
```

Since you can pass a list of rake commands, you could also do this even though it isn't a direct answer to your original question:

```
rake my_arg=foo install upgrade bar
```

Comment: How would `rake my_arg=foo install upgrade bar` work in the Rakefile?