# running RSPEC using a rake task with commandline options that gets passed into the spec file

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

I am trying to run Rspec using a rake task:

```
namespace :smoke_test do   
  begin                        
    desc 'Running Rspec examples using rake'   
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |x|  
      x.pattern = 'smoke_tests/specs/test_spec.rb'   
    end    
    task :default => :spec  
  rescue LoadError    
    # no rspec available   
  end
end
```

The test_specs.rb file contains a variable that is defined in a CommonSettings file, 
(COMMON_SETTINGS($options[:environment])(so that the specs can be run on different environments).

I used the following command to run the rake task and was hoping that the variable gets set in Rspec, but it doesn't (I have a Rakefile that gets the commandline options and validates them etc):

```
rake smoke_test:spec -- --environment=QA_Local
```

I have tried a few other things which are hard to explain here and also looked at other people's questions and answers, couldn't find a very definitive answer.

Comment: `rake RAILS_ENV=QA_Local smoke_test:spec`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rake custom arguments for all tasks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559319/rake-custom-arguments-for-all-tasks)

Comment: I had already tried that, did not work.
mostly the rspec isnt reading the $options[:environment]